# Flutter web FileSaver library for offline use

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web, filesaver.js

I'm currently creating a flutter Web App that will be completely on a local server (intranet). I want to use the file saver library for offline use. I have downloaded the source from Github and included the file like this `<script src="filesaver/src/FileSaver.js"></script>`  before
`<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script></body>`
but it is not working when offline but works when I'm online. In the production environment, my App won't be connected to the internet.